useEffect and promise priority in inital and subsequent renders
I have below code and help me to find the output with accurate explanation.
'infiniteLoopProtection:false'
import * as React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/dom";

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0)
  console.log(1)
  
  const start = Date.now()
  while (Date.now() - start < 50) {
    window.timestamp = Date.now()
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(2)
  }, [state])

  Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(3))

  setTimeout(() => console.log(4), 0)

  const onClick = () => {
    console.log(5)
    setState(num => num + 1)
    console.log(6)
  }
  return <div>
    <button onClick={onClick}>click me</button>
  </div>
}

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App/>)

setTimeout(() => fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('click me')), 100)


Now I am confused how this can be.
Que: How promise and setTimeOut functions are executing before useEffect on initial render but after useEffect on subsequent render?
I tried running it on codeSandbox and got the below output
1
2
3
4
5
6
1
2
3
4

Even I executed the code in codeSandBox and got the same output. But https://bigfrontend.dev/react-quiz/useeffect-timing-iii is not accepting this answer. According to them correct answer should be
1
3
4
2
5
6
1
2
3
4


"How promise and setTimeOut functions are executing after useEffect on subsequent render?" - uh, they aren't? The order is still 1 2 3 4?

Looks like the quiz is wrong. And that's quite possible: effects, timeouts and promises are all asynchronous, you should not depend on any particular order between them. React may have changed this since some older version.

Running for me I get 1,1,2,3,3,4,4,  button click  5,6, 1,1,2,3,3,4,4   Regardless, relying on how micro/macro tasks react (pardon the pun),  seems a massive waste of time, and a totally pointless exercise..  (but is does say quiz), so maybe that's ok.. :)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
